# Can we publish ios App using Apple Developer Enterprise account?

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-developer-program

I have an Apple Developer Enterprise account. Can I publish an iOS app to Apple app  store using an Enterprise account?

Comment: #Sanket Bhavsar, thanks for reply. But the apple developer forum have different answers, Please check this link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11756

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't actually.

Check https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

App Store Distribution is only available for **Individual/Organization**.

And In-house App Distribution exclusively for **Enterprise Program**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @LalKrishna for clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately, this screenshot is no longer accurate. There is a more recent version of this table here: https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: Thanks for the update. Anyway i already included the link to check. Also the image is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise account can't publish by App Store . Enterprise account publish use In-house certificate .

In-house certificate and Distribution certificate can't use common Bundle Identifier . so there will has two app on customer cellphone .

Answer (score 2):

You can not publish apps on enterprise account as app store. It's only for In-house app distribution.

Comment: Please provide a a link of the source or the documentation you got these information?

Comment: https://www.goodbarber.com/blog/how-to-distribute-ios-app-out-of-the-store-with-ios-enterprise-program-a871/

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Developer Enterprise Program is only for the internal use and distribution of proprietary apps. Its not for to add apps to appStore for public.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)

[image]